# Ordered games problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose there are two bots (call them Bot 1 and Bot 2) playing a fighting game match. Each match consists of the bots playing a sequence of rounds, where each bot picks a particular character in the game and fights against each other (resulting in one bot winning and the other losing).

Suppose this game has characters labeled 1 through n. The bots want to simulate real players fighting each other, so they assume that each character has a particular "win-rate" against every other character (assume there are no 100/0 winrates), and winning a round involves a random outcome (win or loss) based on this win-rate. The win-rate when both bots are playing the same character is 50/50.

The bots play a match where Bot 1 starts on character 1 and Bot 2 starts on character n. If a bot loses a round, it stays on the same character and if it wins moves to the next character (Bot 1 from char k to k+1 and Bot 2 from char j to j-1). The bot wins the match if it is the first one to win with all characters.

Intuitively it seems like the probability that either bot wins the match should be the same (50/50) with these conditions and assuming any set of valid win-rates. Is this true? If so, how would one prove this claim?

Comment: Try to do it for a few small $n$ first. Like $n=2$ or $3$. This should help you get a feel for the dynamics of the problem, which will help immensely either to find a counterexample roster of fighters, or to prove that the odds are, in fact, even. It is definitely a cool problem, though. Generalisation opportunity if it turns out to be 50-50: What if they aren't forced to the reverse order of characters? What if the loser can choose their next fighter from among their unused fighters? Is it possible to be strategic, or is it still a forced 50-50?

Comment: Isn't staying  on to the  character after a loss and moving on after a win counter-intuitive if the aim of each bot is to win ?

Comment: @trueblueanil Presumably, the aim of each bot is to get through their roster as fast as possible, and winning lets them move on to the next fighter. I find it intuitive enough. Although ultimately, which outcome of a fight is labelled "winning" and which is labelled "losing" is arbitrary for our mathematical purposes.

Comment: Posted a possible proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4243762/possible-solution-to-ordered-games-problem)

Comment: @Arthur You appear to have misread the description of the game in the same way that I initially did, before I realised that the "characters" aren't other fighters which each of the two bots have to fight against, but personae (presumably with different abilities and/or weapons) which the bots must successively adopt in each match against the other bot